# It is known that $y = ax^2 + bx^3$; when $x = 2$, $y = 5.6$, and when $x = 3$, $y = 25$. Find the values of a and b.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$5.6 = 4a + 8b$$

$$25 = 9a + 27b$$

$$5.6 - 25 = ( 4a + 8b ) - ( 9a - 27b )$$

$$-19.4 = -5a - 19b$$

I'm stuck at that point.

$$a = -1.36$$ $$b = 1.38$$

Comment: There are many ways to solve two simultaneous linear equations in two variables: graphing, elimination, substitution, Cramer's Rule, etc. Which method have you been taught?

Comment: Elimination and substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1: ELIMINATION**

Multiplying the first equation by $9$ gives us that $$50.4=36a+72b$$ Multiplying the second equation by $4$ gives us that $$100=36a+108b$$ Now subtract these two equations which gives us $b$. Now put this back in the first equation to get $a$.

**METHOD 2: SUBSTITUTION**

Dividing the first equation by $4$ gives us that $a+2b=1.4$. So $a=1.4-2b$. Then put this in the second equation, which gives us a equation of the form $9b-12.4=0$, which we can use to find $b$. Now put this back in $a=1.4-2b$ to get $a$.

In Any a case, we get that $$a=-\frac{61}{45}$$ $$b=\frac{62}{45}$$
Though my answer differs from yours, it can be demonstrated that your answer is incorrect: if we put $a=-1.36, b=1.38$, then we get $25.02$ in the second equation, not $25$.

Comment: I understand, what you said about substitution method better, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: @W.Zlacki Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @W.Zlacki From $9b-12.4=0$, we get that $$9b=-\frac{62}{5} \Leftrightarrow b=-\frac{62}{45}$$ Putting this in $1.4-2b=a$ gives us that $$a=1.4-2b=\frac{7}{5}-\frac{62 \times 2}{45}=\frac{63}{45}-\frac{124}{45}=-\frac{61}{45}$$

Comment: Give me a minute I'm still trying to figure it out, plus I just got done eating dinner lol sorry

Comment: $$25 = 9( 1.4 - 2b ) + 27b$$ $$25 = 12.6 - 18b + 27b$$ $$25 = 12.6 + 9b$$ $$12.4 = 9b$$ $$b = 1.38$$

Comment: @W.Zlacki Yes, that is correct. Now that gives us that $9b=12.4$.

Comment: I hit enter before I was done. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to just change one of the equations to be in terms of $a$ or $b$, so a "substitution" approach rather than "elimination".

So from your first equation: 
$4 = 5.6 - 8b$

$a = 1.4 - 2b$

Substitute this into $25 = 9a + 27b$ to get

$25 = 9(1.4-2b) + 27b$

Solve this to get $b$.

Then put this back into $a = 1.4 -2b$